# How to Vlookup from last empty row and autofill to the end of other non-empty columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the last empty row on column "D" and then perform a Vlookup function from matching value from column "A" with another sheet, and autofill this formula down.
The problem is that i'm getting an error in the vlookup.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("IDL MASTER").Range("C:AV")

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Worksheets("Planilha2").Range("A:A")

 

LastBlankRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Cells(LastBlankRow, 4).Select

ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Rng, myRange, 46, False)

ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "D"))

End sub
```

Comment: In the Vlookup you are using as Lookup_Value the entire Column A and it should be a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FillColumnD()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("IDL MASTER")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Planilha2")
    
    Dim lRow_ColA As Integer: lRow_ColA = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lRow_ColD As Integer: lRow_ColD = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim LookupRange As Range: Set LookupRange = ws1.Range("C:AV")
    Dim FillRange As Range: Set FillRange = ws2.Range(Cells(lRow_ColD, 4), Cells(lRow_ColA, 4))
    Dim rCell As Range
    
    For Each rCell In FillRange
        rCell.FormulaR1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rCell.Offset(0, -3), LookupRange, 46, False)
    Next rCell
End Sub
```